# 2 Dimensional array Error in shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
i=$(awk '{x++} END {print x}' mibwithtraps)
echo $i
IFS=","
while read f1 f2 f3 f4
   do
      echo "hell :$f4"
done < mibwithtraps
```

This prints this:

```
7
hell :CRITICAL,
hell :INFORMATIONAL,
hell :CRITICAL,
hell :INFORMATIONAL,
hell :INFORMATIONAL,
hell :INFORMATIONAL,
hell :CRITICAL,
```

I want store these in an array, all my attempts to do so have failed. I've tried this:

```bsh
for ((w=1; w<=i; w++))
    do
       while read f1 f2 f3 f4
          do
             a[$w]= echo $f4
       done
done < mibwithtraps
echo ${a[2]}
```

And what it does is it prints this:

```
7
CRITICAL
INFORMATIONAL
CRITICAL
INFORMATIONAL
INFORMATIONAL
INFORMATIONAL
CRITICAL
```

All of them are being stored in the array as a whole thing. I want them to be separate so that when I do:

```bsh
echo ${a[2]}
```

This should happen:

```
INFORMATIONAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program fails mostly into his logic.

```bsh
for ((w=1; w<=i; w++))
do
    while read f1 f2 f3 f4
    do
        a[$w]= echo $f4
    done
done < mibwithtraps
echo ${a[2]}
```

First, `for ((w=1; w<=i; i++)); do [...]; done < mibwithtraps` makes no sense, since you're redirecting the content of `mibwithtraps` to a `for` loop. Loops don't have `stdin`, they are a language construct, not commands; I assume you wanted to redirect the content of `mibwithtraps` to `read` instead: `while read f1 f2 f3 f4; do [...]; done < mibwithraps`.

Second, you're storing the content of `$f4` starting from `$a{[1]}`, which is the second position of the array, and you're doing it using the wrong sintax; to store the output of a command this way you have to run it in a subshell (`a[$w]=$(echo $f4)`, however you don't even need to do this, because you can simply assign the value of `$4` to the array (`a[$w]=$f4`); but moreover you're storing for each `for` loop each fourth `,`-separated field of each line of `mibwithtraps` at the same position of the array; as a result, with the above correction you would have an array `$a` containing the same fourth `,`-separated field of the last line of `mibwithtraps` value from the second position to the eight position.

To solve this, and as a general rule, I suggest you to store the values into the array while looping through the file the first time; it's unuseful to loop through it twice. Since arrays (as any variable) don't need to be declared in `bash`, you can directly assign a value to an undeclared array; also you can append an element to an existing / non-existing array using the sintax `array+=(<value>)`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

i=$(awk '{x++} END {print x}' mibwithtraps)
echo $i
IFS=","
while read f1 f2 f3 f4
do
    echo "hell :$f4"
    a+=("$f4")
done < mibwithtraps
echo ${a[1]}
```